# How can i split a string of dataframe schema into each Structs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

I want to split a schema of a dataframe into a collection. I am trying this, but the schema is printed out as a string. Is there anyway I can split it into a collection per StructType so that I can manipulate it (like take only array columns from the output)? I am trying to flatten a complex multi level struct + array dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val test = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq("""{"a":1,"b":[2,3],"d":[2,3]}""")))

test.printSchema

val flattened = test.withColumn("b", explode($"d"))

flattened.printSchema

def identifyArrayColumns(dataFrame : DataFrame) = {
    val output = for ( d <- dataFrame.collect()) yield
    {
       d.schema
    }
    output.toList
}


identifyArrayColumns(test)
```

Output currently is

```
identifyArrayColumns: (dataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType]
res58: List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType] = List(StructType(StructField(a,LongType,true), StructField(b,ArrayType(LongType,true),true), StructField(d,ArrayType(LongType,true),true)))
```

It is one full string, so I cannot filter only the array columns. Suppose if I do a foreach(println). I get only one line

```
scala> output.foreach(println)
StructType(StructField(a,LongType,true), StructField(b,ArrayType(LongType,true),true), StructField(d,ArrayType(LongType,true),true))
```

What I want is each StructTypes in a single element in a collection

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve - what is the expected output?

Comment: @TzachZohar - I have added more clarity, please let me know if you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter the `fields` of the DataFrame's schema for fields with type `array` - no need to inspect the DataFrame's *data* for this:

```
def identifyArrayColumns(schema: StructType): List[StructField] = {
  schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.typeName == "array").toList
}
```

NOTE that this is a "shallow" solution that would only return the array fields directly under "root", if you want to also find Arrays within Arrays / maps / structs, you'd need to recursively traverse the shcema and produce this filtered result, something like:

```
// can be converted into a tail-recursive method by adding another argument to accumulate results
def identifyArrayColumns(schema: StructType): List[StructField] = {
  val arrays = schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.typeName == "array").toList
  val deeperArrays = schema.fields.flatMap {
    case f @ StructField(_, s: StructType, _, _) => identifyArrayColumns(s)
    case _ => List()
  }
  arrays ++ deeperArrays
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, is there a way I can get the name from a StructField?

Comment: `StructField` has a `name` method which returns its name, so for `f: StructField` just call `f.name`.